# Better use of the word "sorry"

Tags: word-usage

From what I can tell, there are many ways people use the word "sorry". I'm going to cite 2:

1. A way to show someone else sympathy for something neither of you had any control over. eg. "I'm sorry that your letter was lost in the mail."
2. To apologize for something they did to offend you that they did have control over. eg. "I'm sorry that I was angry with you this morning."

Is context the ONLY way to disambiguate between which version of "sorry" a person is using or is there a better way to use "sorry"? On the same token is there a better word to use than "sorry" in the situations I cited?

The reason I'm asking this is because often times the meaning seems to be lost via miscommunication. ie. the word came across but not in the way the orator meant it. Consider the following example:

- Dave: "I'm going to get a drink from that grocery store, do you want anything?"
- Cindy: "Sure, get me a Coke Zero if they have it. Thanks."
- *5 minutes later*
- Dave: "They didn't have Coke Zero so I bought you a regular Coke instead. *Sorry*."

Did Dave say "sorry" here because he is apologizing for the inconvenience that the store didn't carry Coke Zero or is he saying "sorry" because he failed to bring Cindy her desired drink and feels personally responsable? However frivolous my example may be hopefully you see the point I'm driving at that only Dave knows in which way he said "sorry". I'm hoping one of you can shed some light on this situation in a way that will help me understand how to communicate my "sorry" more efficiently.

Comment: Could be a bit of both, there's no way Cindy would know *exactly* what he was apologizing for, or maybe he wasn't even apologizing and was merely offering his sympathies about her situation. If Cindy **really** wanted to know she could demand "and what, exactly, are you sorry for?"

Comment: 1) Context is the only way to disambiguate between which version of *any* word a person is using. That's what "context" *means*. 2) The meaning of *any* word at all can be lost via miscommunication. That's what "miscommunication" *means*.

Comment: It _is_ ambiguous. To disambiguate and show you're sorry for _your_ actions, you can say 'My apologies'. For the other case, you can say 'Too bad' or something, but it sounds detatched.

Comment: The non-verbal 'Sorry' (not quite a grimace) works better with the 'I regret that circumstances were not more propitious on this occasion' situation. Or you could use  'I regret that circumstances were not more propitious on this occasion' ?

Comment: Maybe another way to disambiguate is the tone or pitch when pronouncing the word *sorry*.

Eg- Mr.A) What have you done?
      Mr B) I'm sorry (statement).
Eg2- Mr.A) My house is in aijfjasfnsdf street.
       Mr.B) Sorry? (question or I beg your pardon tone)

Comment: Given that they are both spelled the same I'm not sure what information is available beyond context...

Comment: This ambiguity can sometimes be quite serious. If a suspect in a crime expresses sympathy by saying they're sorry, someone could interpret that as an apology, which implies an admission of guilt. But most of the time context and common sense make it clear which is intended. If Dave couldn't do anything about the store running out of Coke Zero, it doesn't make sense that he would apologize.

Comment: It's English.  English is like that.  And it would be the lesser if it were not.

Comment: "I am sorry" means "I am filled with sorrow", so it is completely appropriate as a statement of empathy, or regret for one's actions. Those are equally valid situations to be filled with sorrow. So Sorrow is where you should try to make a distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're quite right about the ambiguity inherent in the word *sorry*. If you wanted to avoid the ambiguity, you can consider using the word *sympathise* in place of "sorry" when you want to connote that you don't feel personally responsible for the adverse outcome. Example:

> "I heard about you losing your job and I completely sympathise."

Note that there is a distinction between *sympathise* and *emphathise*, which are often confused with each other.

*Empathise* generally also connotes a shared experience or feeling, a "we're in the same boat, mate" feeling. Here's a modification of the above example where "empathise" would be appropriate:

> "I heard about you losing your job and I completely empathise, *because I recently lost mine too.*"

Unfortunately, if you are merely reading the word *sorry* in someone else's writing, there is no way apart from context to unambiguously infer the meaning. Sometimes, this ambiguity is used purposefully to humorous effect. I remember an example from a Billy Bunter book I read in my childhood (I think it was "Billy Bunter and The Man from South America") - I'm paraphrasing from memory here:

> Bob Cherry (while twisting Billy's ear): *Say "I'm sorry I'm a cad!"*
>
> Billy Bunter: *Ow! I'm sorry you're a cad!*
>
> The rest of the juniors: *Ha, ha, ha!*

I think you get the idea.

Comment: I recently had this conversation with my girlfriend. I theorized that saying "sorry" is sympathetic while saying "I apologize" is an admission of guilt to any uncertain degree. Regardless, there's nothing definitive and still the usage is so relative to the orator! *C'est la vie*

Comment: @Jacksonkr I have had the same conversation with my former wife, sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a better use of sorry, but in the first way of using sorry, you can use upset instead.

Example:
"I'm really upset that your letter was lost in the mail."