# Alternative to "I'm sorry" as meaning "I empathize" when speaking to my spouse

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english

I use the words "I'm sorry" to mean two different things. One being "I apologize for wronging you" and the other, "I empathize with your situation".

90+% I'm using it as the latter, however, my spouse (and other people) often respond along the lines of "It's not your fault".

What is a good alternative to way to convey "I empathize" to my spouse to show her I care for her troubles without always sounding like I'm apologizing?

This question is very similar to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92768/how-to-say-im-sorry-to-express-sympathy-for-misfortune-without-inviting-its) and somewhat [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19334/what-is-it-called-when-the-word-sorry-is-not-used-for-apologizing), however, the answers to those are more targeted at responding to strangers, acquaintances, friends, etc. They are not as relevant for someone I spend a significant amount of time with, and say this to as often as a dozen times a day.

Comment: Try "Oh no, that's really rubbish" or phrases to that effect.

Comment: Have you considered our sister site for [interpersonal.se]?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Gotta be careful with that - on first reading, I thought you were being sarcastic. On the other hand, intonation and body language come into play when the phrase is conveyed in person.

Comment: @tchrist I considered it, but I feel the question is more applicable here because I'm primarily looking for better phrasing rather than the related interpersonal aspects of conveying my attitude.

Comment: @Lawrence, like this?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nq_A6IYJYu4

Comment: I usually say something like 'That's a shame' when I wish to empathise with someone close to me. Or, 'That's annoying' or 'They didn't. did they ?' As you rightly say, 'I'm sorry' is not empathetic enough.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/945/)

Comment: You're looking for a way to say "*I empathize*" to your spouse? The answer is "*I empathize*". If not then the question seems unclear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Better use of the word "sorry"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/255172/better-use-of-the-word-sorry)

Comment: @MaxWilliams [quite](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429618/alternative-to-im-sorry-as-meaning-i-empathize-when-speaking-to-my-spouse?noredirect=1#comment1030932_429618). :)

Comment: I am not going to vote to close this post as a duplicate because the older question is closed because it lacked research, and there's only two answers with the second one being more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Do you think they’re being funny or are they a non-native speaker?  I’d probably go with it and come back with: “Of course it is, I ***told*** the professor to put those questions on the exam.”  Or whatever it was that was clearly not my fault.

Comment: Just an aside: You write that you need to say "I'm sorry" to your spouse to express your empathy *"as often as a dozen times a day"*. That's quite a remarkable statement. You make it sound like everything is going wrong in her / his life. Maybe there's a SE site where you can post the real problem (if you haven't already).

Comment: Do you mean "empathize" or do you really mean "sympathize" and don't understand the distinction between the two words? Empathy implies you have undergone the same experience.

Comment: @Michael_B Interesting comment, and you're probably right that it warrants further thought on my part. I think it's a combination of her being prone to complaining and perhaps somewhat victimizing of herself, and myself prone to empathizing that leads to me saying it so often.

Comment: @David In my opinion, empathize is placing myself with her in the troubles whereas sympathizing is a more removed attitude of "that's unfortunate but it's not my problem".

Comment: @TerekC — Fine, as long as that is really what you mean. But nowadays it is used by people that are not in a position to do that and feel that and use it as a trendy substitute for sympathize.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sorry to hear that.

Then you're not apologizing. You're expressing empathy and compassion.

The response: *"It's not your fault."* doesn't fit anymore.

Even better (especially since it's directed at your spouse):

> I'm sorry to hear that. Is there anything I can do to help?

Comment: or sing it: "Hard to Say I'm Sorry", a 1982 song by Chicago!

Answer (score -1):

I have a very sweet auntie who is always very sympathetic.

She will usually just say *"Oh, sweetheart"* or *"Oh, [first name]"* to show empathy. If the news is really bad, she will say *"Oh, sweetheart, I'm so sorry."*

A lot of it has to do with her tone of voice (descending in pitch). And it's probably the **so**, but you never feel the *"I'm so sorry"* is an apology.